# Unable to run query on table created with Spark using registerTempTable

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have executed below simple script to create a temp table in memory using Spark SQL context

```
import sys.process._
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
val zeppelinHome = ("pwd" !!).replace("\n","")
val bankText = sc.textFile(s"$zeppelinHome/data/bank-full.csv")

case class Bank(age:Integer, job:String, marital:String, education:String, balance:Integer)

val bank = bankText.map(s => s.split(";")).filter(s => s(0) != "\"age\"").map(
    s => Bank(s(0).toInt,
    s(1).replaceAll("\"",""),
    s(2).replaceAll("\"",""),
    s(3).replaceAll("\"",""),
    s(5).replaceAll("\"","").toInt
    )
).toDF()

bank.registerTempTable("bank_tbl")
```

Using SparkSQL, I can see and describe the table using `show tables` and `describe tables` respectively, but when I try to execute query like `select job from bank where age > 35`, it gives me following error -

```
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxx.com:8020/home/zeppelin/data/bank-full.csv
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:285)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:228)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217)
```

Am I missing something here?

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from

```
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://cdtspcentral01d.rxcorp.com:8020/home/zeppelin/data/bank-full.csv
```

The file doesn't exist. I assume you want it to read from the local
filesystem instead.

```
val bankText = sc.textFile(s"file://$zeppelinHome/data/bank-full.csv")
```

Comment: Yes, I want to read it from local filesystem nad I have read it from local filesystem as you can see from my scala code. The table named `bank` is created which I can see it using SparkSQL query. Back to my question, why do I get such error when I try to execute `select` queries in SparkSQL? Why is it saying `Input path does not exist: hdfs://cdtspcentral01d.rxcorp.com:8020/home/zeppelin/data/bank-full.csv`?

Comment: @PRP because you're telling it to look on the hdfs by not explicitly using `file://`.